# Running PHP Scripts from external file

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm writing a module in my CakePHP application to generate receipts in PDF. The PDF generator takes the "content" as parameters and generates the PDF based on it. So I created a template file that looks like this:

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3">
                    Purchase Summary - Receipt
                    <?php echo "PHP CONTENT ECHO";  ?>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
...
```

I read the content like this:

```
$file = file_get_contents('receipt_template', true);
```

I want to pass this content to the PDF generator. When I print the content, none of the  commands are being executed, so the line `<?php echo "PHP CONTENT ECHO";  ?>` never gets executed. 
I was thinking to have template file, load the content and just substitute the values, then pass the whole thing to PDF generator to create the PDF document. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Marc B.
with `ob_start(); include('yourfile.php'); $executed_data = ob_get_clean();` I can achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents()` does NOT execute any code. it simply sucks in the file's bytes and stuffs those bytes into a variable.

If you want to execute any PHP in the external file, you'll have to `include()` or `require()` it.

Comment: Yeah, but include() outputs the content in the browser, I want to store the content in a variable so later I can pass it to the PDF generator.

Comment: `ob_start(); include('yourfile.php'); $executed_data = ob_get_clean()`.